# When i am coping any content from any website then always a static content will copy from there?

Tags: javascript

Recently i have seen an feature in a website of https://aninews.in/. If you try to copy any text then you can copy only previous set content. i think it made with js! help me

Comment: Do you mean it won't let you copy any text? It lets me copy and paste fine.

Comment: Please explain clearly what it is that you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.clipboardData.setData('text', 'hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to cancel the copying, try this:

```js
let can  = document.querySelector('span#can');
let cant = document.querySelector('span#cant');

cant.addEventListener('copy', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<span id="can">Copy this</span>
<br>
<span id="cant">Can't copy this</span>
<br>
<textarea>

</textarea>
```

If what you want is to cancel the copying **and** copy something else, try this:

```js
let can  = document.querySelector('span#can');
let cant = document.querySelector('span#cant');

cant.addEventListener('copy', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'canceled');
});
```

```html
<span id="can">Copy this</span>
<br>
<span id="cant">Can't copy this</span>
<br>
<textarea>
</textarea>
```